# Using single function to open a modal popup from multiple links

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function to open modal popup. This is working fine when i click a link. The link is like:

```
 <a href='' class='click' id = "myLink"><b>Click Here to See Popup! </b></a>
```

And the jquery function is written like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function () {
            var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');         

            $('.click').click(function () {
                overlay.show();
                overlay.appendTo(document.body);
                $('.popup').show();
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

My requirement is to use this function to be called from multiple links. Because I want to use the id of link. For example in the above code i want to use "myLink" in function. How can I pass id of every link used to open modal popup to the jquery function above? Thanks.

Comment: `this.id` inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function scope `this` should be link element, so you can use `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: Don't use `attr` to get a native property as it's just adding needless overhead. `this.id` is perfect.